# glm lookAt and matrix transformation yielding odd behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transformation

I am using `glm::lookAt` to get a matrix to transform the world by. This works fine, I can generate the matrix, the feed it into the shader, and it all works. What I now need to do is transform an arbitrary vector (ie 100,100,100,1) by the `lookAt` matrix.  For some reason, I get garbage values

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(current_pos.x,
                                        current_pos.y, 
                                        current_pos.z),
                              glm::vec3(current_pos.x + dir.x,
                                        current_pos.y + dir.y, 
                                        current_pos.z + dir.z),
                              glm::vec3(up.x,up.y,up.z));
GLfloat fmodel[16] =
{
    model[0][0],
    model[0][1],
    model[0][2],
    model[0][3],

    model[1][0],
    model[1][1],
    model[1][2],
    model[1][3],

    model[2][0],
    model[2][1],
    model[2][2],
    model[2][3],

    model[3][0],
    model[3][1],
    model[3][2],
    model[3][3]
};
```

A printout of `model`'s values: `0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3`
I am calculating the point using `model * vec4(x, y, z, 1)`

The matrix is duplicated so I can pass it as a uniform.  Both using the original matrix an constructing the matrix from the array yield identical results.

EDIT

Printing code is as follows:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
  printf("%d,", fmodel[i]);
```

This yields the output of `3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` no matter what my vectors are

Comment: What is your vector specifically and what result do you get?

Comment: Why duplicate the matrix? `model` is already a `float[16]` array,

Comment: The vector specifically is 100, 100, 100, 1.  Different values don't change the result.  The result's values change with each invocation of the program, like those of uninitialized variables.  Duplication is done so I can pass the matrix as a uniform, which requires it to be a float array

Comment: What values `current_pos`, `dir`, and `up` do you feed into `lookat`? There must be some mistake in your printing code, as `glm::lookat` can't possibly generate such a matrix. Side note: Use `glm::value_ptr()` on a matrix/vector to get a float array.

Comment: `current_pos` is initially 1.5,100,6.  `dir` is a normalized vector pointing along -z.  `up` points +y.  However, when these change, the matrix output doesn't.  I was unaware of `glm::value_ptr()`.  I will update the code to reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, after using `glm::value_ptr()` rewriting large swathes of code, this is now working